# RDLC - How to search & count specific value in row and show result in Last Column?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working report that display individual Leave of each day of the month in which last column shows total number of AL (Absent-leave) in a month.
The only problem in report is the Wrong count of Total Number of AL .

[Currently I'm getting output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnsy5.png)

[Ideally, I'd want the output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFJya.png)

I'm using the code below to get the result set below that:

```
            =Sum(IIf((Fields!num1.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num2.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num3.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num4.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num5.Value="AL") OR
            (Fields!num6.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num7.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num8.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num9.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num10.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num11.Value="AL") OR
            (Fields!num12.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num13.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num14.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num15.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num16.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num17.Value="AL") OR
            (Fields!num18.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num19.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num20.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num21.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num22.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num23.Value="AL") OR
            (Fields!num24.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num25.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num26.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num27.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num28.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num29.Value="AL") OR 
            (Fields!num30.Value="AL") OR (Fields!num31.Value="AL"),1,0))
```

I follow many stackoverflow solution but not working.

Comment: It may be a better option to do this calculation in your SQL rather than in the RDL. Have you considered that?

Comment: @R.Richards I'm using NoSQL